# Running multiple statements with a loop in a single `python -c` text string

Tags: python

I'm running a small snippet using `python -c` string statement, but don't seem to get the syntax right when I' using a for loop and defining variables. Help appreciated.

This works:

```
python -c "for i in (1,2,3):    print(i)"
```

A simple definition prior to the loop errors:

```
python -c "a = 123; for i in (1,2,3):    print(i)"
> Syntax Error
```

A simple definition after the loop works:

```
python -c "for i in (1,2,3):    print(i); a = 123"
```

Comment: Is there any chance that you could forget `"` after `print(i)` in the 2nd statement?

Comment: Sorry that was my typo pasting into SO